# Why was the saw scene cut from Ferdinand the Bull?

Tags: alternate-version, ferdinand

**Ferdinand (2017)** recently aired on **Now TV** in the UK as part of the **SKY** network.

In the scenes in the slaughter house, **Ferdinand** and **Valiente** are attempting to free **Guapo**. The rails take them through the meat tenderiser. Then their faces show shock/surprise and then an very awkward cut shows them both on the same hook as **Guapo**.

I have found a YouTube video recorded off a TV showing this scene and what should be shown is the two trying to avoid a circular saw in the floor.

There is no blood or anything else that should cause this to get cut over the other instruments of death in that location.

Does anyone know why this was cut from the UK broadcast?
Is it in the UK DVD/Blue-ray release?
Does Sky/Now TV/BBFC routinely cut circular saw scenes where no injury/blood occurs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the U.K., the film has an age rating of 'U', which is for any age.  The full UK cut film received this rating - see here: http://www.bbfc.co.uk/releases/ferdinand-2017

However, the film did seek advice to receive that rating prior to release:

> Precuts information
>
> During post-production, the distributor sought and was given advice on how to secure the desired classification. Following this advice, certain changes were made prior to submission
>
> Note: The following text may contain spoilers
>
> This film was originally seen for advice, at which stage the company was informed it was likely to be classified PG uncut but that their preferred U could be achieved by removing a single use of mild bad language ('bloody') and reducing various scenes of mild threat and dangerous behavious involving electricity. When the film was submitted for formal classification all these issues had been addressed satisfactorily and the film was classified U.

The scene you refer to may be included in the above, and therefore all U.K. Releases (including Blu-Ray for the region) will be cut the same.

Also consider, Perhaps it was cut for length for that specific broadcast, or cut for internal business policy of Sky.  The only way to find out is to contact Sky directly.